# Extract httpd.conf from Apache2 in Docker container

Tags: apache, docker

I want to extract the default httpd.conf file from Apache2 inside a running Docker container so that I can customize it. I have found plenty of examples to help me going the other way but nothing that helps me going in this direction.

Comment: `docker run  your_apache_image:latest bash -c "cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf" > default.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can copy it from container:

```
docker cp containername:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf .
```

and return it to the container:

```
docker cp apache2.conf containername:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: In some apache2 installations the file is located at /usr/local/apache2/conf but the rest of your answer helped me get it